# Gravid female red eared slider

Tags: aquarium, aggression, breeding, turtles, stress

So it's the time of the year where last year on April 29,2019 my female red eared slider who is turning 4 soon layed her eggs but this time she hasn't. I moved her to her nesting area today (29th April,2020) because she showed  signs of restlessness as she tried to come out of her tank. I'm sure she's gravid because I can see the swelling near her tail. I'm concerned for her because when I moved her to her nesting area she tried to come out in less than half an hour and that's not the only reason. Last week while cleaning her tank the  water was reddish brown and in between the glass there was blood. As of that day I have separated her from the male turtle and there's no blood. But is that the cause of her not laying her eggs? Does she need more time before laying the eggs?

Comment: Please, could you write how your actual question differs from this (of you too): https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25314/my-female-red-eared-slider-as-far-as-im-guessing-is-gravid?

Comment: It's a little different from last time because this time she is not staying in her nesting area where as last time I had asked a similar question she was comfortable and did her work in her nesting area. Yesterday all she did was stay there for roughly 15mins and then was agitated to come out

Comment: How is this working? Do you bring her daily to the nesting place? Aside the organisation problems: if you are worried about the health of your turtle ("blood in the water") visit a vet! Do not wait for the guesses of strangers from the internet...

Comment: About the blood there are no turtle vets available in my region to visit n since I haven't seen blood as of that day I'm hoping she's all better (though the blood could be from the male as well). As for her nesting area I wasn't sure if I should remove if she's not ready to lay her eggs

Comment: Males and females of red eared sliders in nature are loner. They only meet to make little turtles and then go their own ways again. I assume you have not more than two square meter room for your turtles, so they could not avoid each other in your tank. This could cause aggression and hurting. Same for the eggs: if the turtle could not choose the time for the nesting area itself it it is possible she laid some eggs into the water, which she and the male could have eaten so you only see blood. And for the "no vet": you could call a turtle vet, equal how far it is, this would be better than nothi

Comment: Also about the vets I've tried but most vets end up not experienced in turtles and have quite a little clue.