# Terrapin laying eggs! Help!

Tags: behavior, health, breeding, turtles, eggs

So I adopted 2 terrapins 5 days ago. The female 'Babs' layed 2 eggs yesterday (1 crushed and 1 didn't). I've checked her over and she feels like there's another 4 eggs to be layed. I've set up a box with sand and put her into it to finish laying and nothing! How long should it take for her to lay the other eggs before I should start worrying? I've taken her out and put her back into water and given food and she looks like she is looking for a spot, but I am afraid the eggs are going to bind. It's been about 36 hours since she layed the other 2. Any advise please?

Comment: Welcome! If you are afraid about the health of your pet, do not wait for answers from some strangers from the internet. Go and make an appointment with a turtle-experienced vet! I wish you and the two the best!

Comment: You could read this to make the sand box most comfortable for your turtles: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25314/my-female-red-eared-slider-as-far-as-im-guessing-is-gravid/25315#25315